# No gentiles in gehinnom?

Tags: gentiles, mysticism-kabbalah, gehinnom

I was listening to a discussion, and the Rabbi said that some of the sages had the opinion, that non Jews do not enter gehinnom.

This is the second time I have heard this.

My question is as follows. Is it the opinion of some, that Gentiles vanish after death, even if they are wicked?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9166/do-jews-think-that-all-the-unbelievers-would-go-to-hell-someday

Comment: Interesting I have seen several sources that say clearly the opposite? E.g. See the Sifrei on Devarim 311 - https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.311.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I’m just wondering what the opinions were that gentiles don’t go to gehinnom

Comment: Honestly - I'm yet to see that written in any sources. I can only count several early sources that say the reverse?

Comment: This is the first time I ever heard of such a thing and I can think of explicit Gemoras that make reference to evil non-Jews being in Gehinom. If these rabbis are Orthodox and scholars then they must have been referring to some sort of subsection of Gehinom that non-Jews aren't sent to

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. Did he say that non-Jews don't go to gehenom, or that being a non-Jew doean't mean spending time in gehenom? I think that's an easy misspeech, for a rabbi to say "non-Jews don't go to gehenom" and forget to say, "all go to..." or "... because they're not-Jews" Or whatever it was he meant along those lines.

Comment: It is quite possible that the source being referenced by the lecturer was discussing the different levels of hell, of which Gehinom is only one. There are 6 other levels and each level pertains to a particular type of Tikkun.

Comment: I don't have a source offhand, but I have heard this idea before. The idea (as I recall it being explained) is that Gehinnom is meant to be a place to cleanse one of sins in order to allow them into Gan Eden. However, if a non-Jew is evil, they don't go to Gan Eden, so therefore there is no benefit in 'cleansing' then through Gehinnom, so they simply 'cease to exist'. This is not necessarily in contradiction with the sources that say gentiles can go to Gehinnom, as it may depend on how wicked they are and whether they still have a share in Gab Eden in addition to sins that need to be cleansed.

Answer (score 1):

Chazal say in [Bereishis Rabbah (78,5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.78.5?lang=bi):

> וַיִּזְרַח לוֹ הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ וגו' (בראשית לב, לב), אָמַר רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה וּלְמִי לֹא זָרְחָה הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ, אֶלָּא לוֹ לִרְפוּאָתוֹ, אֲבָל לַאֲחֵרִים אוֹרָה. רַב הוּנָא בְּשֵׁם רַב אַחָא אָמַר, כָּךְ הָיְתָה הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ מַרְפֵּא בְּאָבִינוּ יַעֲקֹב וּמְלַהֶטֶת בְּעֵשָׂו וּבְאַלּוּפָיו. אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אַתְּ סִימָן לְבָנֶיךָ, מַה אַתְּ הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ מַרְפֵּא בְךָ וּמְלַהֶטֶת בְּעֵשָׂו וּבְאַלּוּפָיו, כָּךְ בָּנֶיךָ תְּהֵא הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ מַרְפֵּא בָהֶן וּמְלַהֶטֶת בְּעוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים, מַרְפֵּא בָהֶן (מלאכי ג, כ): וְזָרְחָה לָכֶם יִרְאֵי שְׁמִי שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה וּמַרְפֵּא בִּכְנָפֶיהָ, וּמְלַהֶטֶת בְּעוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים (מלאכי ג, יט): הִנֵּה הַיּוֹם בָּא בֹּעֵר כַּתַּנּוּר וגו'. וְהוּא צֹלֵעַ עַל יְרֵכוֹ, רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי הֲוָה סָלֵיק לְרוֹמִי, וְכֵיוָן דַּאֲתָא לְעַכּוֹ נְפַק רַבִּי חֲנִינָא לְקַדְמוּתֵיהּ, אַשְׁכְּחֵיהּ מַטְלַע עַל יְרֵכוֹ, אֲמַר לֵיהּ אַתְּ דָּמֵי לְסָבָךְ וְהוּא צֹלֵעַ עַל יְרֵכוֹ.
>
> (my translation)
> "And the sun shone upon him" (Bereishis,32,32). R' Berachiya said; To who does the sun not shine for? Rather it {the shining of the sun}  was healing to him, for others however it was light." R' Huna said in the name of R'Acha; "So was the sun {a source of} healing to our forefather Yaakov and {the light of the sun} burned Eisav and his mercenaries. God said to him {Yaakov}: "You are a sign for your children, just as for you the sun was healing and burned Eisav and his mercenaries, so too for your children the sun is healing and burns idol worshipers, it {the sun} is healing for them {Yaakov's children}, {as it states:} "And it shall shine for you, those who revere my name, a sun of righteousness and healing with its wings" (Malachi,3,20), and shall burn idol worshipers, {as it states:} "Behold the day is coming, burning like a furnace, all the arrogant and all the doers of evil shall be straw, and the day is coming, said the Lord of hosts, shall burn them to ashes leave of them neither roots nor branches" (ibid,19).

The reference to idol worshipers burning from the rays of the sun is referred to by Chazal elsewhere as the experience of Gehinom.

[Bereishis Rabbah (6,6):](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.6?lang=bi)

> רַבִּי יַנַּאי וְרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן תַּרְוֵיהוֹן אָמְרִין אֵין גֵּיהִנֹּם אֶלָּא יוֹם שֶׁהוּא מְלַהֵט אֶת הָרְשָׁעִים, מַה טַּעַם (מלאכי ג, יט): הִנֵּה הַיּוֹם בָּא בֹּעֵר כַּתַּנּוּר וגו
>
> R' Yannai and R' Shimon both say, there is no Gehinom other than the day when he {God} burns the wicked. For what reason? {because the verse states} "Behold a day is coming burning like a furnace etc." (ibid).

This seems to imply that indeed Non-Jews enter Gehinom.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As per the comments above, the OP wanted to know specifically if non-Jews don't enter Gehinom. There are plenty of sources that say they do enter gehinom but that's not what he's after....